# How to show/hide an radio button dependant on option set field CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm newbie on javascript. I'm triying to hide an radio button when a user choose a specific value of the option set. I have wrote this script

```
function showhideradiobuttom(){
var optValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("nav_phone1type").getValue();

if (optValue == 1) {
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("nav_phone1spam").setVisible(false);
}
else {
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("nav_phone1spam").setVisible(true);}
}
```

Unfortunatelly this is not working...

Comment: are you running your code on `OnChange` event? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes, i'm runnig the code in Onchange event of radiobutton

Comment: No, your function should be running on change of option set. Let me know if it working.

Comment: You are rigth. I have runned the code in option set and it is working! Thank you!

Comment: cool, I will convert my comment to an answer and then you can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are running your javaScript function on the `OnChange` even of Option Set.